# how to wait until localStorage.setItem finishes in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, local-storage

i am developing an angular 4 application. once the user wants to log in to the system it sends a http request to the server and server validate the user and it sends a reposnce with a authentication key and other user details. i use local storage to save these information

```
login() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    this.serviceUserService.authenticate(this.loginForm).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.message != "_err") {
        //saving the current user in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response.body));
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      } else {
        alert("invalid login. Please try again")
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
}
```

it seems like that `localStorage.setItem()` is an asynchronous function. so before it save the curent user in the local storage it redirect to the main page. but since the token is not saved in the local storage no http requests will work. how do i wait until `localStorage.setItem()` finish it's task and then send the user to home page.

Comment: And how do you know that redirection is happening before the item is saved?

Comment: That's not an async call.

Comment: localStorage.setItem is not asynchronous, but call to subscribe is. So depend on what is in html could happen redirect is executed before http request is finished. In simplier words - function login() will be finished earlier than response=> part of subscribe. Try comment out call to service and observe what happens (if redirect still occurs).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In case anyone is getting the same kind of a issue... the reason for this was I have created a variable in my service class to save the current user and set the value for that variable inside the constructor. So, in the login page when the `authenticate` method gets called it tries to initialize the variable but since user is not logged in yet it is still `null`. That was causing the issue.

Comment: You should show the erroneous code in the question, and the solution in the answer. Otherwise, this answer is pretty useless to others.

Answer (score 8):

You are wrong , all localStorage calls are **synchronous**. Probably you can add a check before navigating to the next page.

```
 localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response.body));     
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
```

Comment: What's the point of the `if`? You just set the item, so you know `getItem()` will be successful.

Comment: Thanks.I added 
`if (localStorage.getItem('MY_KEY') === 'YES') { window.location.assign(a_url) }`, then my program works.

Comment: What check?  Is a check even necessary if it is synchronous?